# What is a good Django file-browser for non-admin users?

Tags: django

Do any of you know of a Django app out there for allowing users to browse for files, and upload new ones? The ones I have found seem to be built as an add-on for the admin interface (django-filebrowser, django-filer).

Not aiming for anything incredibly complex, just something that allows a user to upload files and then browse between folders (either specific directories on the server, or artificially generated "folders" out of some model field).

I recall the admin tutorial mentioned "The admin isn’t intended to be used by site visitors. It’s for site managers."

My thought from above is that it would be bad practice to simply allow users to see content via the admin interface, and that it would be better to create an app to allow for this.

Comment: what all you tried till now , where is the code for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the convenience that your end users usually expect in the age of google drive, you really want a complex javascript filebrowser that plays nicely with django.

I'm using [yawd-elfinder](https://github.com/yawd/yawd-elfinder) which is a great django backend for [elfinder](http://elfinder.org/) to manage my students' association's website with great success ( About 1500 users with different groups and privileges).
Features:

Yawd-elfinder can manage local files but also use Django filesystem storages to connect to remote filesystems. A set of django options allows control over file and directory permissions, accepted mime types, max file sizes etc.

It allows you to have fairly complex management of files and different permissions for different users by activating different roots and/or mapping them differently based on the user.

Furthermore you have capabilities like drag and drop, upload by drag and drop and it's very customizable.

I'm not sure it's maintained anymore, but you can find working code [here](https://github.com/arpheno/eestecnet/tree/master/apps/elfinder) with the relevant [views](https://github.com/arpheno/eestecnet/blob/master/apps/elfinder/views.py) and [templates](https://github.com/arpheno/eestecnet/tree/master/apps/elfinder/templates/elfinder).

Comment: Thanks, sounds like this is something that could do exactly what I want. I'll give this a look.You allow the filebrowser to be accessed from the external users it sounds like?

Comment: Hey Sebastian - I'm facing a weird bug where permissions for specific users do not seem to always work as intended. All users share the same root, and I restrict folders within that root from the Root(dict) class in models.py by using user.has_perm(). If I log off of a specific user, and log in as another my permissions will sometimes be the same as the previous user until I restart the web server. Any ideas what could cause this?